# some old ash-tot

Tags: meaning

> I've seen him with Sir Huon and the Lady Esclairmonde stepping
>   just as they stepped to avoid the track of Cold Iron in a furrow, or
>   walking wide of some old ash-tot because a man had left his swop-hook or
>   spade there;

This is from *"Rewards and Fairies"* by Kipling.
What does *"some old ash-tot"* mean?

Comment: I suspect *ash-tot* means an ash-heap, or ash-pile; a place where someone has dumped ashes.  I haven't been able to find an exact reference for that, but ["totting" is apparently British slang for "searching through rubbish for usable or saleable items"](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/totting), which may stem from *tot* meaning a place for dumping trash.

Comment: Thank you so much, also this time! It is very helpful for me.